# Passing a variable from phtml to CMS block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a need to sending data from block creation place in .phtml to my CMS block.

I create the block on the .phtml as follow

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'); ?>
    <?php if ($category->getShortDescription()) : ?>
          <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock(
               'Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('short_description')->setData('sd','Hello Short')->toHtml();?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here, I'm passing a parameter to the block as `setData('sd','Hello Short')` But the parameter is not showing on the cms block

I call this parameter/argument on my blog as

```
The Short Description is {{sd}}
```

But I expect the output should be `The Short Description is Hello Short` but I `The Short Description is {{sd}}`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by replacing the text on CMS Block.

```
<?php if ($category->getShortDescription()) : ?>
            <?php
            $shortDescriptionBlock =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'Magento\Cms\Block\Block',"",["short_desc" => $category->getShortDescription()])->setBlockId('short_description')->toHtml();
            echo str_replace("{{short_description}}", $category->getShortDescription(), $shortDescriptionBlock);?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```